# Exporting to Excel in Safari

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, safari, cross-browser, export-to-excel

I am working on a web product that I recently converted from .NET 1.1 to 3.5.  There are several pages we are working on making Mac/Safari compatible.  I have several other issues that were caused by JavaScript fixed.  However the Export to Excel and Word are still unresponsive.

We have an included .aspx page that contains script C# to do the export, since this functionality is so widely used on the site.

It exports just fine in IE, but no response in Safari or even Firefox.

I am using .NET Framework 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.  The code for exporting the data follows:

```
private void PageExcelClick_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            HideListBox_LB();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            this.EnableViewState = false;
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            divPageResultPanel.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();     
            ShowListBox_LB();
        }



private void HideListBox_LB()
{
         foreach(Control cnt in Page.Controls)
    {
        if(cnt.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            Control ctlLB = cnt.FindControl("divExcelExportHide");
            if(ctlLB != null)
                ctlLB.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

private void ShowListBox_LB()
{
     foreach(Control cnt in Page.Controls)
    {
       if(cnt.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            Control ctlLB = cnt.FindControl("divExcelExportHide");
            if(ctlLB != null)
                ctlLB.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update:

I have tried to completely remove the Included aspects of the page. I have put the Export login directly in the codebeing and even pulled the menus onto the page.

#### Update #2:

Have turned code into a user control, export working now!

Comment: Debugging running Safari, it doesn't even register the click event for the Excel button, while the breakpoint is hit from IE.